# VB.Net Renamed 'Form1.vb' then it broke

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have been working on this project for 4 days now. When I finished everything, I renamed the window form. When I renamed `Form1.vb`, my project broke and I could not use it as a Window form, or compile anymore.

**What did I do wrong?** When I renamed it, the `Form1.vb` icon changed to an icon with VB on it.

**Error:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   BC30451 'Button1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  Design  C:\Users\vaste\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Design - kopia\Design\hrthtrhtrrhthrt.vb   344 Active

Answer (score 2):

The Winform window class is a partial class that is defined over two files - the class file and the designer file. Check that the class name was changed in both form1.designer.vb and form1.vb. You may need to click the Show All files button on the Solution Explorer toolbar to see these separate files.